# How do I change the an app's ui to correspond with change in account type in flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes

I'm trying to change some parts of my app's ui in response to pressing the switch button (similar to how Instagram's ui switches from personal account to professional/creator account) but I don't know how to go about implementing it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the singleton/state management class with a variable. The variable can hold the type data. Then access from any class and make a decision which part will be visible / or not. You may use setState or other state management like Getx/Provider/Bloc.

Comment: Took me a while to get the hang of it but it works, thanks.